# Get all contacts and their details (e.g. postal address) in one OUTER JOIN query

Tags: android, contacts, contactscontract

I know how to retrieve contact data for specific contacts. However, i can't find a way to get all contacts plus some of their details in a single query. The following code gets all contacts **having** a postal address:

```
  Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI;
  String[] projection = new String[] {
    StructuredPostal._ID,
    StructuredPostal.LOOKUP_KEY,
    StructuredPostal.DISPLAY_NAME,
    StructuredPostal.STREET,
    StructuredPostal.CITY
  };
  String sortOrder = StructuredPostal.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
  Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, sortOrder);
```

But what i need are **all** contacts, whether they have postal address or not. Is this doable using the ContatsContract API, or do i need to create custom outer join query? Any hints on how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All contact information in Android 2.0 is stored in a single database table. So you can get all the information you need in a single query:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
    null, null, null, sortOrder);
```

The just iterate through the data and check `Data.MIMETYPE` column. For example, if this column has `StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE` value, then you can get `StructuredPostal` fields from this column.

Comment: Indeed, but it requires the post-processing. I was hoping to get the right result Cursor right out of the query, so that i can feed it directly to a list view adaptor. But this will also do, thank you for the idea!

Comment: I think this is old and no longer valid? Looks like now phone number is stored at a different URI.

Answer (score 4):

if You have a contact ID and you want to fetch the Postal Address then use this :

```
         Uri postal_uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI;
         Cursor postal_cursor  = getContentResolver().query(postal_uri,null,  ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "="+contactId.toString(), null,null);
          while(postal_cursor.moveToNext())
            {
             String Strt = postal_cursor.getString(postal_cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredPostal.STREET));
             String Cty = postal_cursor.getString(postal_cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredPostal.CITY));
             String cntry = postal_cursor.getString(postal_cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
            } 
            postal_cursor.close();
```