# Unable to get contact address from the phone contact

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to get an address from a phones contact with no luck, I am able to get the name, phone number and email, but not the address. When debugging the cursor for StructuredPostal looks the same as for the phone number. I have 'android.permission.READ_CONTACTS' set in my manifest, hence getting the other info.
This is the code I'm using:

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickContact(),
        onResult = {
            val contentResolver: ContentResolver = ctx.contentResolver

            val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
                it!!,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null)
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    changed = true
                    clientUiState.clientDetails.clientname =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))
                    Log.d("Name", clientUiState.clientDetails.clientname)
                    val id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))
                    val postal: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
                        StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS + " = " + id,
                        null,
                        null
                    )
                    if (postal != null) {
                        while (postal.moveToFirst()) {
                            clientUiState.clientDetails.clientAddress =
                                postal.getString(postal.getColumnIndex(StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS))
                            Log.d("Address", clientUiState.clientDetails.clientAddress)
                        }
                        postal.close()
                    }
                    val phones: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
                        Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id,
                        null,
                        null
                    )

                    if (phones != null) {
                        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                            clientUiState.clientDetails.clientPhone =
                                phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER))
                            Log.d("Number", clientUiState.clientDetails.clientPhone)
                        }
                        phones.close()
                    }

                    val email: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
                        Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        arrayOf(id),
                        null
                    )
                    if (email != null) {
                        while (email.moveToNext()) {
                            clientUiState.clientDetails.clientEmail =
                                email.getString(email.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA))
                            Log.d("Email", clientUiState.clientDetails.clientEmail)
                        }
                        email.close()
                    }
                   
                }
            }

        }
    )
```

Also tried ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), but same results. I'm still a noob so probably missing something basic, or barking up the completely wrong tree, and have been unable to an answer elsewhere on the net.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally found the answer to this problem in an old (2012) post https://stackoverflow.com/a/13471370/22445779.

```
val postal: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
                        StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + id.toString(),
                        null,
                        null
                    )
                    if (postal != null) {
                        if (postal.count == 0) clientUiState.clientDetails.clientAddress = ""
                        while (postal.moveToNext()) {
                            clientUiState.clientDetails.clientAddress = postal.getString(
                                postal.getColumnIndex(StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS)
                            )
                        }
                        postal.close()
                    }
```